# PowerShell - Import-CSV - How can I keep leading zeros on all decimal numbers being imported

Tags: powershell, decimal, import-csv, export-csv

I am trying to perform changes to a existing CSV, such as keeping specific columns (and removing the rest). However when I use Import-CSV, the leading zeros on certain data is being converted from 0.123 to .123 and -0.456 to -.456.  This is leading the program that will digest this information to reject it.

My code looks something like this:

```
Import-CSV $attachment | Select-object 'column1', 'column2', column3' | Export-CSV $output
```

I appreciate any help you can provide.  Thank you.

Comment: Post a sample row, with at least the column value you are referring to. I tried to reproduce and could not, 0.123 was imported as string (along with any other values I attempted).

Comment: The implication is that whoever _consumes_ your CSV interprets the value as _numbers_, resulting in reformatting. `Import-Csv` only ever imports values as _strings_, and, similarly, `Export-Csv` performs no interpretation of string values on export.

Comment: I'm guessing you are looking at the csv file using Excel. To prevent Excel removing leading zeroes from numbers, prefix the values with a TAB

Comment: I have to apologize, the originating data is already abbreviated.  I will look into solutions to adding the leading zeros needed in before importing the csv.  Thanks.